# import value from python in kv file

Tags: python, label, kivy

I have a python code and kv file. I want to use a value (an array) made by python in kv file. Im more details, I have two screen. In main screen, the is a button. the "value" is filled in python code after pressing this button. Then the results of the "value" should be shown in the second screen. 
 my python code is:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    def btn(self):
        value=k #here we define the value. it is an array
class ResultWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Then I want to use this 'value' in the ResultWindow. So, this is my kv file:

```
WindowManager:
   MainWindow:
   ResultWindow:
<MainWindow>
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            on_press: root.btn()   #so here we make and access to the value
            on_release:
                app.root.current= "resultwindow"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
<ResultWindow>:
    name:"resultwindow"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        Label:
            text: str(root.value(0))
```

so, the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultWindow' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weird thing about kivy is that it likes to build all the screens before it does anything. The nice thing about your app is at least you have a starting screen that makes it easier to update the label on the second screen before you get there. They way I have done it, and you will see below, is that I set the label to an empty string then when the btn function is called it sets the value to whatever it is you want to use then sets the text for the label on the second screen based on whatever it is you set it to in the function. Here is the code with just an example for value.

.py:

```
from kivy import *
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MainWindow(Screen):
    def btn(self):
        MyMainApp.value = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]  # here we define the value. it is an array
        #ResultWindow.ids.label_one.text(MyMainApp.value[0])
        self.manager.get_screen('resultwindow').label_start_one = MyMainApp.value[0]


class ResultWindow(Screen):
    label_start_one = StringProperty(' ')


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("mymain.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

    value = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    ResultWindow:

<MainWindow>
    name: 'main'
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            text: 'press'
            on_release:
                root.btn() #so here we make and access to the value
                app.root.current= "resultwindow"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<ResultWindow>:
    name:"resultwindow"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        Label:
            id: label_one
            text: root.label_start_one
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Millions of thanks. Wow. You solved my big problem. My main program is a bit different from what I told, so I have to work more on it. But, logically I understand how to solve it. Best wishes for you and have a great day.

Comment: Glad I could help. Have a great one